# TRUNC in oracle leaves minutes

Tags: oracle

I have a doubt with the use of `TRUNC` function in Oracle. As read in the documentation:

> The `TRUNC (date)` function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model `fmt`

I tried this code on my Oracle client:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM') "Today's Date and Time"
from DUAL;
```

But all what I get is this: `10/26/2017 12:10:00 AM`

It isn't supposed to be `10/26/2017 00:00:00 AM`?

By the way, the `SYSDATE` is this: `10/26/2017 10:10:05 AM`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format string is not correct.

`HH:MM:SS` should be `HH:MI:SS`.

Also, when using the 12 hour format, midnight is 12:00:00 AM, not 00:00:00 AM.